# Constant integers and constant evaluation

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr int f() {
  if (std::is_constant_evaluated())
    return -1;
  else return 1;
}

int main() {
  int const i = f();
  std::cout << i;
}
```

It [prints `-1` when run](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MKfrdFZkAqXVQ2CJ) (wandbox).

However, if I make the function `throw` when evaluated at compile time::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr int f() {
  if (std::is_constant_evaluated())
    throw -1; // <----------------------- Changed line
  else return 1;
}

int main() {
  int const i = f();
  std::cout << i;
}
```

it [compiles fine and outputs 1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8HnS4EXTLwhDd8xw) (wandbox). Why didn't I get a compile failure instead?

Comment: AFAIK you are not allowed to throw in a `constexpr` function making the 2nd program UB.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh yes. I forgot to mention! Yes, if `i` is annotated `constexpr` then it fails to compile.

Comment: @NathanOliver I know. I have seen this technique to make deliverately to fail to compile. You are allowed to throw, but not in the codepath being constant evaluated.

Comment: Yep.  Just did some more looking and it is okay as long as it is not the path taken.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Isn't constant evaluation fun?

There are a few places in the language where we *try* to do constant evaluation and *if* that fails, we fallback to doing non-constant evaluation. Static initialization is one such place, initializing constant integers is another.

What happens with:

```
int const i = f();
```

is that this *could be* constant evaluation, but it doesn't necessarily have to be. Because (non-`constexpr`) constant integers can still be used as constant expressions, if they meet all the other conditions, we have to try. For instance:

```
const int n = 42;       // const, not constexpr
std::array<int, n> arr; // n is a constant expression, this is ok
```

So try we do - we call `f()` as a constant expression. In this context, `std::is_constant_evaluated()` is `true`, so we hit the branch with the `throw` and end up failing. Can't `throw` during constant evaluation, so our constant evaluation fails.

But then we fallback, and we try again - this time calling `f()` as a non-constant expression (i.e. `std::is_constant_evaluated()` is `false`). This path succeeds, giving us `1`, so `i` is initialized with the value `1`. But notably, `i` is *not* a constant expression at this point. A subsequent `static_assert(i == 1)` would be ill-formed because `i`'s initializer was *not* a constant expression! Even though the non-constant initialization path happens to (otherwise) entirely satisfy the requirements of a constant expression.

---

Note that if we tried:

```
constexpr int i = f();
```

This would have failed because we cannot fallback to the non-constant initialization.

Comment: another reason why not use `const` for thing that should be compile time constant.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: C++03 tried to use `const` to mimic the `constexpr` it didn’t have; of course we should use the real thing now.

Comment: The fun thing is that `f()` is a core constant expression if it is evaluated *not* as a constant expression.  That’s why we have to have the language about “manifestly constant evaluated”.

Comment: OT but I am really curious about the implementation. If it is magical, I wonder why it is not a keyword.

Comment: What I find interesting here is that the second `f()` is also a theoretical optimisation opportunity, if the compiler is sufficiently skilled at logical inference.  "If `std::is_constant_evaluated()`, then `f()` throws.  This is invalid in a constant expression, thus it isn't a constant expression if `std::is_constant_evaluated()`.  `f()` is therefore never a constant expression, and therefore `std::is_constant_evaluated()` must always be `false`."  It could then in theory optimise to `constexpr int f() { return 1; }` since the `true` branch is provably unusable (but technically reachable)...

Comment: ...But, ironically, would then be left as a function that can only be "evaluated" at compile time in conditions where it's _not_ a constant expression.  (A smart compiler would be able to inline it and replace `f()` with just `1`, but as throwing `f()` cannot be a valid constant expression, it would only be allowed to do so in situations where inlining it wouldn't result in a constant expression.)  [All of this is, of course, strictly theoretical.  An interesting quirk nonetheless, though.]